# Singing with allergies and asthma?

Tags: voice, self-learning, health

Save your voice while being sick but it gets blurry with allergies and asthma. I can hear an allergic reaction from my voice before I can feel anything, like playing Singstar and a pet visiting. The volume of lungs can greatly vary during allergic season from more normal. So how should you train singing with allergies and asthma?

Comment: I hope someone has some good ideas.  That's a challenge to say the least.  Many allergy medicines designed to relive the symptoms have the effect of drying the mucous membranes which is very bad for singers.  So one thing I would suggest is that the type of allergy drugs that are antihistamines or otherwise dry up mucous membranes or have a dehydrating effect should not be used for several days prior to singing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe practicing or singing during an allergy or any infection is very dangerous as it gives a lot of strain to the already strained muscles of the throat. A proper medication is really required to recover. Yoga, meditation and breathing exercises really help for singing. Either ways, a good exercise and a good balanced diet is required to maintain a good voice and good health. A humidifier is required since it helps keeping the air moist. You'll definitely bounce back once you regularly practice after the recovery of asthma or allergy.

Happy Singing :)

Comment: +1 for nice suggestions. Many allergy/astmma medicines make things dry and sound very different. Is a humidifier a portable machine?

Comment: Yes few are portable, "evaporative", "cool moisture", or "wick humidifier", consists of just a few basic parts: a reservoir, wick and fan. Sorry for the late reply.